# Notification click while app is in foreground and background

Tags: android, android-notifications, onesignal

I have an app where users spend most of their time solving puzzles in `GameFragment` which is in `MainActivity`. I don't save users progress and if they quit the app before the level gets cleared then their progress for that level is lost and they will have to start anew.

From time to time, I am sending push notifications that when clicked users are given 100 diamonds as a reward.

The problem is, if a user clicks on the notification while playing the game or when the game is in the background, then the game is being recreated from `SplashActivity` and then goes to `MainActivity` which hosts `GameFragment`. Additionally, there are two of the same app are open now in the task bar. What I want is that when user clicks the notification, the notification should disappear and tell `MainActivity` to reward the user without recreating the whole app again.

How can I achieve this? I am using OneSignal to send push notifications.